Can one define a data type that wraps values of only those types for which an instance of a particular multiparameter type class exists?
Here is code illustrating the problem:
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}

class SomeClass a b where
  someFunction :: a -> b -> a

data FirstInInstanceOfSomeClass = forall a. (forall b. SomeClass a b) => First a

instance SomeClass Bool String where
  someFunction = const

x = First True {-
               • No instance for ‘SomeClass Bool b’
                   arising from the head of a quantified constraint
                   arising from a use of ‘First’
               • In the expression: First True
                 In an equation for ‘x’: x = First Truetypecheck(-Wdeferred-
                 type-errors)
               -}

I want x to be a valid value since there is an instance of SomeClass for Bool, i.e., the one with String. Is there a way to achieve this?
Clarification: there might be many instances of SomeClass where Bool is in the first position. What I want to require is that there shall be at least one such instance for Bool so that FirstInInstanceOfSomeClass may wrap Bool values.
Edit: generally speaking, b does not functionally depend on a.

This should be straightforward with GADTs, but you'll probably have a better time if, say, there's a unique b for a.

Your FirstInInstanceOfSomeClass doesn't make sense: you want a to be a parameter, not existential, and then b should be existential, not universal (as in (exists b. SomeClass a b) => First a, or equivalently forall b. SomeClass a b => First a by currying, which is the syntax Haskell supports).
data FirstInInstanceOfSomeClass a = forall b. SomeClass a b => First a

Of course, the compiler now complains that b is ambiguous in the type of First; one way to fix that if you have a functional dependency of b on a is to just declare it:
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class SomeClass a b | a -> b where
  someFunction :: a -> b -> a

Otherwise you can use AllowAmbiguousTypes and TypeApplications:
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

data FirstInInstanceOfSomeClass a = forall b. SomeClass a b => First a

x = First @_ @String True

Or Proxy:
import Data.Proxy

data FirstInInstanceOfSomeClass a = forall b. SomeClass a b => First (Proxy b) a

x = First (Proxy :: Proxy String) True


Thank you for your answer. Could you elaborate on how I can use Proxy or GADT?

You can do the following to store the value:
class    Class a b         where someFunction :: a -> b -> String
instance Class Bool Int    where someFunction _ _ = "this instance"
instance Class Bool Double where someFunction _ _ = "that instance"

data Data where First :: forall a b . Class a b => a -> Data

value :: Data
value = First @_ @Int True

The @Int helps to picks the Class Bool Int instance to create the value.

Though, I don't think that you can pattern match value to recover the specific instance to use the method though -- at least not without changing the definition of Data and storing the Int type in it as well.
I.e, this won't work:
test :: String
test = case value of First a -> someFunction a (1 :: Int)

